# javascript fire cntrl plus + and cntrl + -(minus) event onf button click

Tags: javascript, zooming, keyboard-shortcuts

i want to create button which fire event cntr plus + event on click for zooming web browser window, actually i am trying to zooming whole page on button click.

```
function fullPagePlus()
{
 $(window).width($(window).width()+100)
}
```

i tired this code but this is not working   i want to fire shortcut keys on single button click is there any way ? i also tried this code but its not working on mozilla firefox

```
document.body.style.zoom="300%"
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the below code and update us if this is what you want. refer the [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/tBjN6/3/).

Zoom function is not supported by Firefox. It can be seen [here](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/zoom) and the code is as below.

```
window.max = function () {
    document.body.style.webkitTransform =
        document.body.style.msTransform =
        document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + 3 + ')';
    document.body.style.width = 100 / size + '%';
}
```

transform is used instead of zoom, as zoom is not supported by Mozilla.

Happy Coding